# What does "B-grade" mean in the context of Japanese food?

Tags: meaning, foreign-phrases

In movies, "B-grade" refers to lower-budget movies:

> When Hollywood studios were at their height -- and before television
> was available -- it was common for people to spend an entire evening
> at the movies, where there would be a main feature, a second feature,
> a newsreel, and cartoons. The main feature would be the "A" film; it
> used the leading stars, and had a bigger budget. The second feature
> would typically be a movie that used lesser talent, and had inferior
> production values and less sophisticated plots. These films -- which
> were consciously made to be second-rate in this way -- were called "B
> movies", just as the "B" side of a record would not be the song that
> was popular, but just something else included because it was expected.
>
> The term has come to be used in general conversation to mean "**of inferior quality**, and **appealing to less sophisticated tastes.**"
> Source: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1352120

But what is B-grade Japanese gourmet food?:

> 1. These days, so-called **"B-grade gourmet" foods** are getting popular even among foreigners
> 2. Popular **B-grade gourmet** of the Osaka, a Review ranking.
> 3. Enjoy savoring **grade B gourmet foods** from Tokyo!
>
> Sources: [1](http://www.travelience.com/blog/about-japanese-food-sushi-tempura-ramen-soba-etc/), [2](http://gurutabi.gnavi.co.jp/en/gourmet/2/pref27/), [3](https://www.gotokyo.org/en/tourists/topics_event/topics/120514/topics.html).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it refers to: "more humble, simpler food that is more accessible, but no less delicious that [kaiseki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiseki), which is Japanese *haute cuisine*." I have also seen it called "[*Japan's comfort food*](http://blog.lingualift.com/japans-b-grade-gourmet/)."

> Japan's many fine restaurants have a world-class reputation for
> gourmet fare, but the national focus of late is on a different "class"
> of gourmet--simpler, more accessible, but no less delicious to its
> ravenous fans.
>
> "B-grade gourmet" is now wildly popular and portrayed in the media as
> tasty, much-beloved local cuisines which are often variations of
> national favorites such as ramen, udon or yakisoba. B-grade gourmet
> dishes are all appealingly priced, from ¥300 to ¥700 (US$3.50-8.50).
> Essentially, this is ordinary food that can be enjoyed by anyone--but
> B-grade gourmet is prepared with devotion and flair.
>
> Hugely popular B-grade events draw "gourmets" from all over the
> country who sample these different dishes, and then vote for the
> tastiest offering. At some events, winners are chosen based on the
> weight of piles of chopsticks accumulated from voters.
>
> If a dish ranks highly at a B-grade gourmet event, people pour in from
> all over the country to line up at the local restaurant that serves
> it--a kind of gourmet tourism that helps revitalize that town or
> region. Some B-grade dishes may also allude to the history or customs
> of a community, and thus endure as an important part of Japan's
> diverse culinary culture. Local municipalities and other groups have
> taken the hint, participating in B-grade events to harness the
> economic stimulus of hungry tourists.
>
> Regional B-grade cuisine may involve a simple noodle dish or a more
> esoteric reflection of local tastes. Some recent winners include
> Yokote yakisoba, a straightforward dish of fried noodles from Yokote
> in Akita Prefecture; more adventurous palates may prefer Kofu
> torimotsu-ni, simmered and glazed chicken giblets in soy sauce-based
> sauce from Kofu in Yamanashi Prefecture.
>
> Locals in Hachinohe, Aomori Prefecture enjoy Hachinohe senbei-jiru,
> wheat-flour wafers added to a broth containing meat, fish and
> vegetables. Shizuoka oden from Shizuoka Prefecture involves simmered
> kuro (black)-hanpen: steamed, minced fish, vegetables and meat in a
> rich dark soy sauce-based broth, sprinkled with aonori seaweed and
> dashi powder. Hearty Atsugi shirokoro horumon from Atsugi in Kanagawa
> Prefecture, consists of plump pork intestines cut into bite-size
> pieces and grilled in their original tubular shape.
>
> Source: http://www.kikkoman.com/foodforum/spotlightjapan/32.shtml